# ¿Como retornar los valos de una archivo de texto?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Esta duda que tengo está dirigida al manejo de archivos en C#.
Tengo un archivo de texto y lo que requiero hacer que la consola me muestre los datos de la fila según el dato que coloque dentro del arreglo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      
        string[] datos2 = null;
        datos2 = LeerArchvioTXT();
        LeerArchvioTXT();
        MuestraDatos(datos2);


    }

    public static string[] LeerArchvioTXT()
    {
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();
        string ruta;

        ruta = @"C:\Users\Contpaqi\Documents\Nexxus v1\Ejemplos txt de kimera\FA11621.txt";
        StreamReader fic = new StreamReader(ruta);

        string linea = null;
        linea = fic.ReadLine();


        while ((linea != null))
        {
            lista.Add(linea);
            linea = fic.ReadLine();
        }


        //SEPARAR SEGÚN EL CARÁCTER " | " Y ALMACENAR LOS DATOS EN UN ARRAY
        char[] separador = { '|' };
        string[] DatosCol;
        DatosCol = lista[0].Split(separador);



        //Creo el array para meter los campos. 

        string[] Datos;

        Datos = null;

        for (int i = 0; i <= lista.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Datos = lista[i].Split(separador);

        }
        

        return Datos;

    }


    public static void MuestraDatos(string[] Datos)
    {


        Console.WriteLine(Datos[2]);


        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Lo que me muestra es el dato correcto, sin embargo solo me muestra el ultimo dato, es como si buscara el primer dato y siguiera buscando y al final se queda con el ultimo dato encontrado.

Mi txt:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento imprimir en pantalla, es a partir del 02, me muestre el dato 3 de cada una de las lineas 02. Es decir, que me muestre esto:

Licencia Comercial Premium 
Carcinoembrionario Antígeno, Suero
CA 125 Antígeno, Suero

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, si estoy mal formulando la pregunta me disculpo, ya que es mi primera en este foro.

Comment: para que realizas 2 veces el llamado al metodo leerArchivoTxt? 



datos2 = LeerArchvioTXT();
        LeerArchvioTXT();

Comment: Hola ger, gracias por responder, he visto ese pequeño detalle y ahora solo hago un llamado. Pero continuo con la duda, la verdad no se como hacerlo.

Comment: No entiendo la logica de tu codigo ni que queres mostrar. Si lees un archivo con multiples lineas, en la variable linea solo te quedas con la ultima que lees... tal vez si explicas mejor que queres hacer podamos decirte mejor...

Comment: gbianchi♦, gracias por responder, ya he editado la pregunta, espero se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basándome en tu código y si entendí bien lo que quieres hacer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

internal class Program
{
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var datos = LeerArchvioTXT();
    MuestraDatos(datos);
}

public static List<string[]> LeerArchvioTXT()
{
    List<string> lista = new List<string>();
    string ruta;

    ruta = @"C:\Users\Contpaqi\Documents\Nexxus v1\Ejemplos txt de kimera\FA11621.txt";
    StreamReader fic = new StreamReader(ruta);

    string linea = null;
    linea = fic.ReadLine();

    while ((linea != null))
    {
        lista.Add(linea);
        linea = fic.ReadLine();
    }

    //SEPARAR SEGÚN EL CARÁCTER " | " Y ALMACENAR LOS DATOS EN UN ARRAY
    char[] separador = { '|' };
    string[] DatosCol;
    DatosCol = lista[0].Split(separador);

    //Creo el array para meter los campos.

    //Remuevo esto
    //string[] Datos;
    //Datos = null;

    //Creo una variable nueva que seria una lista del arreglo, la cual va guardar todos los renglones del archivo
    List<string[]> archivo = new List<string[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= lista.Count - 1; i++)
    {

        //Validar que el renglon no este vacio:
        if (lista[i].Trim().Length > 0)
        {
             //Paso el arreglo la variable Archivo
             //aqui se va insertando RENGLON por renglon, claro en ya separado en forma de arreglo
             //al utilizar split se genera string[], un arreglo string y este lo estoy guardando en una lista de  string[]
             archivo.Add(lista[i].Split(separador));
        }
    }

    return archivo;
}

public static void MuestraDatos(List<string[]> Datos)
{
    //Recorro cada renglon dentro de datos
    foreach (var renglon in Datos)
    {
        //Numero de columna quiero imprimir del renglon actual
        int indiceDeLaColumna = 2;
        //Tomo solo esa columna para ese renglon
        //2021-02-27 Validar que el indice de la columna no quede fuera del arreglo o que no sea mayor a la longitud del arreglo
        if (indiceDeLaColumna < renglon.Length)
        {
            //Tomo solo esa columna para ese renglon
            Console.WriteLine(renglon[indiceDeLaColumna]);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
}
```

Comment: Hola Cristina, muchas gracias por la respuesta y la ayuda. Pero marca el siguiente error: Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error CS1503 Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'string[]' a 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string[]>'

Comment: Hola Cristina, he solucionado el detalle, pero ahora me marca: indice fuera de los límites de la matriz.

Comment: Eso es porque seguramente la posición o la columna que quieres no existe dentro del array... deja modifico el código y agrego validación para eso

Comment: Gracias, me ha salido lo esperado, ahora tengo un nuevo detalle, me gustaría que muestre esos tres campos mas el 3 campo de la segunda lía, ya hice las modificaciones pero no he sale el resultado, lo que me muestra es la 3 letra de cada linea. Tendrás alguna sugerencia.

Comment: Claro con mucho gusto, podrías añadir el código nuevo que creaste y actualizar tu pregunta?  o publicar otra pregunta tambien XD