# ¿Como pasar datos de un metodo a otro metodo?

Tags: c#, consola

Buen día.

Tengo un problema, ya que tengo un método el cual lee un archivo de texto y lo divide en lineas (LeerArchvioTXT).
En el MAIN, unicamente estoy haciendo la lectura a partir de la linea 2, es decir, de la linea 02, ya puedo leer cualquier dato.
Lo que me poder realizar ahora es crear un método donde puede leer unicamente los datos de las lineas 02, y otro método donde pueda leer la linea 01 y otro método donde pueda leer la linea 00, pero NO SE COMO HACERLO.
Me gustaría alguna sugerencia, ejemplo u orientación de como podría realizarlo.

Esto es lo que llevo de codigo, como se puede ver tengo Producto y Clientes, donde producto me muestra las lineas 02 del txt, lo que no puedo realizar es que me muestre en producto la linea 01 del txt.

```
        #region LeerArchvioTXT
        public static List<string> LeerArchvioTXT()
        {
            List<string> lista = new List<string>();
            string ruta;

            ruta = @"C:\Users\Contpaqi\Documents\Nexxus v1\Ejemplos txt de kimera\FA11621.txt";
            StreamReader fic = new StreamReader(ruta);

            string linea = null;
            linea = fic.ReadLine();

            while ((linea != null))
            {
                lista.Add(linea);
                linea = fic.ReadLine();
            }
            return lista;


        }

        #endregion


        public static Linea[] Producto()
        {
            List<string> Datos = LeerArchvioTXT();
            Linea[] lineas = new Linea[Datos.Count - 2];

            //Arreglo que permite leer datos del cliente sin el FOR
            string[] DatosC;
            DatosC = Datos[1].Split('|');
            

            //FOR para leer los datos de los productos linea por linea
            for (int a = 2; a < Datos.Count; a++)
            {
                char separador = '|';
                string[] DatosCol;
                DatosCol = Datos[a].Split(separador);
                lineas[a - 2].Codigo = DatosCol[2];
                //Console.WriteLine(DatosCol[2]);  //Imprime las 3 lineas
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(Datos[3]);
            return lineas;
            

        }

        public static Linea[] Cliente()
        {
            List<string> Datos = LeerArchvioTXT();
            Linea[] lineas = new Linea[Datos.Count];


            for (int c = 1; c < Datos.Count; c++)
            {
                char separador = '|';
                string[] DatosCol;
                DatosCol = Datos[c].Split(separador);
                lineas[c - 1].Codigo = DatosCol[2];
                //Console.WriteLine(DatosCol[2]);  //Imprime las 3 lineas
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(Datos[3]);
            return lineas;

        }



        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Linea[] p = Producto();
            Console.WriteLine(p[0].Codigo);    //imprime el primer producto
            Console.WriteLine(p[1].Codigo);    //imprime el segundo producto
            Console.WriteLine(p[2].Codigo);    //imprime el tercer producto


            Linea[] c = Cliente();
            Console.WriteLine(c[2].cCliente); 

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }

  
    }
```

Contenido del txt:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si es por consola... que tiene que ver asp.net??? no entiendo para nada tu problema... una lista o un array se pasa de un lado a otro como cualquier otra variable... cual seria el problema particular?

Comment: Hola Geovani, veo que anteriormente creaste una pregunta similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/431164/como-retornar-los-valos-de-una-archivo-de-texto te sugerimos que revises el documento [ask] el cual te proporciona informaciòn de como formular preguntas en el sitio y obtengas buenas respuestas, agrega màs informaciòn o detalles a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: No termino de entender la dificultad de tu pregunta. Si podes llamar al metodo desde otro metodo tranquilamente y luego extraes los datos que necesitas nada mas.

Comment: Ya lo he editado, espero se entienda mejor.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como retornar los valos de una archivo de texto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/431164/como-retornar-los-valos-de-una-archivo-de-texto)

Comment: Esa parte la ya le tengo implementada, lo que no puedo hacer es que muestre un dato de la linea 01.

Comment: Lo he editado nuevamente, con el código que intento implementar.

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado.